# Null when trying to load a JSON from Root PCL Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hi when trying to load a JSON file from the root of my PCL it breaks on this line Using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) and says its null.

here is the full method for loadJson()

```
public void LoadJson()
{
    //Loads the JSON File in the Solution and Finds Correct ID of Accordion Hopefully!!
    var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MCETimeTest.TimeSheet.json");

    string jsonString = "";
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    };

    uoObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
}
```

Edit: when stepping through the code stream is always null

and my classes for my json are:

```
 //JSON Classes
    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class Checks
    {
        public DateTime TheDate { get; set; }
        public string JobNumber { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan On1 { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Off1 { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan On2 { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Off2 { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string SingleHours { get; set; }
        public string TimeHalfHours { get; set; }
        public string DoubleHours { get; set; }

    }

    public class LineItem
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public List<Checks> Checks { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: what exactly is in your jsonString, and what is the object class looking like you are trying to connect it to

Comment: @BugFinder I have updated my code to help abit more

Comment: Have you tried 'using (var reader = new StreamReader("MCETimeTest.TimeSheet.json"))' instead of creating Stream object separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also looking over the solution it turns out that the JSON File in the root was not an Embedded Resource. After changing it, it works! sorry for the hassle!